# CsvHelper delimeter character same as end of line character

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I've run into an issue while parsing some csv-like files that I know how to fix, but like to confirm if that's the appropriate way to do.

---

#### The file structure

The file I'm trying to parse has a structure **similar** to `.csv` in that it's values are separated with a delimeter (in my case it's `|`), but different to the ones I've previously seen is that it also has a delimeter at the end of the line, e.g:

```
Column1|Column2|Column3|
Row1Val1|Row1Val2|Row1Val3|
Row2Val1|Row2Val2|Row2Val3|
```

---

#### The issue

The problem arose when I wrote some unit tests to cover my service that wraps over the CsvHelper library. Apparently there is some issue when I provide the following configuration:

```cs
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    Delimiter = "|",
    HasHeaderRecord = true,
    NewLine = "|\r\n"
};
```

With the above configuration, `csvReader.GetRecords()` returns no results. I believe that's because the order of operations for the parser is to first look for columns, then end of line - and it tries to parse empty column without realizing it's actually part of the delimeter.

(I can paste the code for the getRecords call as well, but it's basically generic code taken from examples - the only difference is I'm using `System.IO.Abstractions` library for easier unit testing)

---

#### The attempts to solve the problem

If I remove the `NewLine` configuration value, parser works fine when reading the file (even if it has end-of-line delimeter character at the end). Then, however, my "write CSV" tests break, since CsvHelper no longer is adding proper line endings to the file.

---

#### The question(s)

Is there any way I can configure CsvHelper to cover both cases with one configuration, or should I basically use two different configurations, depending on whether I'm writing to CSV or reading from it? This seems a little bit counter-intuitive for me, since it's basically the same format I'm trying to follow, but different configurations are expected?

Comment: I would argue that `|\r\n` is not the EOL terminator, but just that you have an empty field before the EOL terminator.

Comment: Why is `NewLine` defined as `|\r\n` and not `\r\n`? Also, if the file isn't generated by Windows, it might not be `\r\n` but just `\n`.

Comment: @Neil I agree 100%.

Comment: @Neil This is the format that I receive the files (and am expected to send responses) in - it's defined by the documentation provided to the system I have been tasked to integrate with.

Comment: @Llama please see above comment

Comment: Can't you just have an empty column with no name to satisfy this?

Comment: @Llama this seems as an even bigger workaround than what I've proposed. Have you read through my whole question?

Comment: Have I read through your whole question where you suggest treating an empty column with no name as part of a newline delimiter? Yes.

Comment: Like I said - this is how End of Line is structured in the file I receive. I do not have the possibility to alter the contents of this file - I receive it that way.

Comment: @Llama It is explicitly specified as `#7C #13 #10`.

Comment: Maybe the problem is your file is 'similar to' CSV is the problem.  Its not CSV, and libraries that handle CSV are not suitable.

Comment: @Neil As you can see from my question, I do not have an issue with parsing the file - I manage to do this with two different configurations. I was asking more out of curiosity if it's possible to make it cleaner with one configuration. Also - I have been searching through the internet and cannot actually find any good definition of what a CSV file should look like - is it officialy standardized somehow? At least there is not much about line endings.

Comment: @Neil This is a valid CSV, if you consider that it has 4 columns and the final column has no name. Perfectly valid. Just need to set the NewLine to '\r\n'.
We'd need to see the code doing the writing to be able to advise on how to ensure the trailing empty field is written.

Comment: It's not valid CSV.  What does the C stand for? Hint its not "pipe" !

Comment: @Neil CsvHelper is capable of understanding a different delimeter than a comma :) If you look at [csv] tag I used, even in definition it says that *usually* it is a comma, but doesn't have to be a comma.

Comment: On Windows a \n is "\r\n", on *nix, a line terminator is just \n.  You can use System.lineSeparator() if you really want to make it system agnostic.  https://www.javatpoint.com/post/java-system-lineseparator-method  If you are on a *nix system and you get DOS line endings, there are utilities to convert them like unix2dos or dos2unix.  Working with cross platform files is still a PITA, but these are things you should always be aware of.

Comment: As a general comment, the last column in a csv file is terminated by the line terminator, so in your case it would be col1|col2|col3  having a pipe character after the col3 would be an empty column

Answer (score 0):

You could manually write the empty column for each line and then you could keep the configuration the same for reading and writing.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        Delimiter = "|"
    };
    
    var records = new List<MyClass>
    {
        new MyClass {Column1 = "Row1Val1", Column2 = "Row1Val2", Column3 = "Row1Val3"},
        new MyClass {Column1 = "Row2Val1", Column2 = "Row2Val2", Column3 = "Row2Val3"}
    };

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter("file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, config))
    {
        csv.WriteHeader<MyClass>();
        csv.WriteField(string.Empty);

        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            csv.NextRecord();
            csv.WriteRecord(record);
            csv.WriteField(string.Empty);
        }       
    }

    using (var reader = new StreamReader("file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        var importRecords = csv.GetRecords<MyClass>();
        importRecords.Dump();
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public string Column3 { get; set; }
}
```